# How to get contextual filter of a view from page.tpl.php?

Tags: theming, views

this is my page view path /news/[years]/[month]

I want to get year and month from path, how can do it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [arg()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7) function.

> Returns a component of the current Drupal path.
>
> When viewing a page at the path "admin/structure/types", for example,
>   arg(0) returns "admin", arg(1) returns "structure", and arg(2) returns
>   "types".

In your case:
arg(1) = [year]
arg(2) = [month]

Comment: arg() is perfectly fine and works almost everytime... But remember - when you are dealing with Ajax, the path could be `system/ajax` so `arg(0)` would be `system`. +1

Comment: this one also return an array of contextual filters arguments `views_get_page_view()->args`